# I can't see the .png file as image but as background image it works

Tags: html, css, sass, gulp, png

I'm making a Landing page and I want to put there some **png images** links but they don't show. When I set png as background image I saw it on the page but casual `<img>`doesnt work. Path of the file is okay, I'm sure of that, but console says `"404 file not found"`.When I'm using exactly the same path as bg image it works perfectly I don't know why... I'm writing styles in SCSS and using components for different parts of the site if it matters.
Plz help I'm new T.T

here are the links

```html
<div id='media'>
    <a target='_blank' href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook">
        <img src="/src/images/facebook.png" alt="ikona facebooka">
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn">
        <img src="/src/images/linkedin.png" alt="ikona linkedin">
    </a>
</div>
```

and structures of my folders looks like that:

```html
./src:
 ../fonts
 ../images<--here are the png files
 ../js
 ../sass
 ../templates:
   .../components
   ...index.html
./web:
 ../css
 ../images
 ..index.html
```

Comment: the src folder is not supposed to be directly visible but rather is transformed bu the build system (you have put "gulp"). Try removing the "/src/" part or use "/images/..."

Answer (score 0):

Your styles.css file is located in a different place than your template files so the path SHOULD be different.

From your stylesheet location
`web/css/style.css -> ../../src/images/filename.png`

From your template location
`src/templates/index.html -> ../../web/images/filename.png`

Here's what to do to troubleshoot file paths:

- Open dev tools => network tab (select `images` in your case)
- Look for the file in question
- If it's 404ing your path could be bad.
- Try to load your image in a new browser tab with the full URL path you THINK it should be. (**make sure it's serving properly**)
- Then check that full/serving file URL against the URL in your code

Is this a WordPress site? If so make sure to output the full path with

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/path/filename.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the '/' from the beginning of the image path.
So change this:

```
<img src="/src/images/facebook.png" alt="ikona facebooka">
```

To this:

```
<img src="src/images/facebook.png" alt="ikona facebooka">
```

Comment: Unfortunately i've tried this and png still doesnt show. I tried many things with paths and nothing helped :/